# How to use Babel on files that imports using path aliases?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, babeljs, alias

I'm setting up my build script in order to do server-side rendering on some routes of my web app. I'm using React and Firebase. Right now, my project structure is.

```
root

> buildScripts        // Some build scripts to replace some import paths

> functions
  > distApp           // React app files (src folder down below) transpiled to Node v10
  > distFunctions     // Cloud functions files transpiled to Node v10
    function1.js
  > src               // Cloud functions files written in ES6
    function1ES6.js
  index.js            // indexES6 transpiled to Node v10
  indexES6.js         // index.js written in ES6
  package.json        // Dependencies for functions

> src                 // React app files written in ES6
firebase.json         // Firebase configuration
package.json          // Dependencies for client
```

What I'm planning to do as my build flow:

- Transpile function files in ES6 to Node v10 environment. From `functions/src` to `functions/distFunctions`.
- Transpile `functions/indexES6.js` to `functions/index.js`
- Transpile App files from `root/src` to `functions/distApp` **(THAT'S MY CURRENT PROBLEM)**

I end up using some path aliases to make some `imports` throughout my App a little bit clearer. Like the ones listed below:

**jsconfig.json**

```
"paths": {
        "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
        "@constants/*": ["./src/constants/*"],
        "@helpers/*": ["./src/helpers/*"]
      }
```

And when I'm building to production (client browser code) I'm dealing with those paths with Webpack. I add a `resolve` property so Webpack knows how to handle them. And bundles it correctly.

**webpack.config.js**

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
      '@constants': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/constants'),
      '@helpers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/helpers')
    }
  }
```

So Webpack knows how to resolve and replace those imports. But Babel does NOT.

Then, when I'm transpiling all of my app files in my `root/src` folder to my `functions/distApp`. Babel keeps those imports untouched. `require('@components/something');`

And, as expected, my `functions` code have no idea to where `@components` resolves to.

**QUESTION**

How can I access those `imports` during the Babel transpiling process and update them? Is there a plugin that could do that? How can I handle this?

**PS:** I would like to keep using path aliases, because deep files importing shallow files can get pretty ugly. Like `import helper from '../../../../../../../helpers/someHelper';`. And when I import like that, if I move the file around, I break the import immeadiately, whilst `import helper from '@helper/someHelper'` does not break at all.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver` plugin and specify aliases there, almost in the same way you did it in `jsconfig.json`, but in `.babelrc` file.

Comment: I have an additional question to this answer; is the babel plugin module resolver will also transpile that module? I tried, but apparently it doesn't (I am referencing a module which is outside the project, a common directory with React components). I have also a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62528471/using-components-from-an-external-directory-in-a-electron-project-with-webpack, with the exact issue.

Comment: This is a good question. But I think it should transpile it if in your webpack configuration this folder is 'included' as a folder.

Comment: In fact, it is definitely transpiled, otherwise I would get a JSX-related error. The issue is more like why I am getting "Invalid Hook Call Warning". This is really hard (impossibe?) to debug, unfortunately...