# Using components from an external directory in a Electron project with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, react-hooks, webpack-4

I am trying to do this as simple as possible, I studied Yarn Workspaces for a while, but that's a solution that's currently doesn't work with Electron, there were simply too many issues.

- I have am Electron project here: ./electron/
- I have a directory with components here: ./common/

The components are developed in React/JSX, there is nothing really fancy about them. That said, I am using hooks (useXXX).

I tried many ways to include those components (ideally, I wanted to use Yarn Workspaces, but it only multiplied the number of issues), but they all failed. Which is why I would like to avoid using yarn link or workspaces or making the common a library, etc. I just want my Electron project to behave as if the files were under ./electron. That's it.

The closest I came to a solution is by using electron-webpack, and overriding it with this config:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config = merge.smart(config, {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          //include: /node_modules/,
          include: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../common'),
          loaders: ['react-hot-loader/webpack', 'babel-loader?presets[]=@babel/preset-react']
        },
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@common': Path.resolve(__dirname, '../common')
      }
    }
  })

  return config
}
```

I can import modules, and they work... except if I use hooks. And I am getting the "Invalid Hook Call Warning": https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html.

I feel like that /common folder is not being compiled properly by babel, but the reality is that I have no idea where to look or what to try. I guess there is a solution for this, through that webpack config.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. That happens because the instance of React is different between /common and /electron.

The idea is to add an alias, like this:

```
'react': Path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
```

Of course, the same can be done for other modules which need to be exactly on the same instance. Don't hesitate to comment this if this answer it not perfectly right.

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I wrestled more than a day with a similar problem. My project has a dependency on a module A that is itself bundled by Webpack (one that I authored myself). I externalised React from A (declaring it to be a commonjs2 module). This will exclude the React files from the library bundle.

My main program, running in the Electron Renderer process, uses React as well. I had Webpack include React into the bundle (no special configuration).

However, this produced the 'hooks' problem because of two instances of React in the runtime environment.

This is caused by these facts:

- module A 'requires' React and this is resolved by the module system of Electron. So Electron takes React from node_modules;
- the main program relies on the Webpack runtime to 'load' React from the bundle itself.
- both Electron and the Webpack runtime have their own module cache...

My solution was to externalise React from the main program as well. This way, both the main program and module A get their React from Electron - a single instance in memory.

I tried any number of aliases, but that does not solve the problem as an alias only gives direction to the question of where to find the module code. It does nothing with respect to the problem of multiple module caches!

If you run into this problem with a module that you cannot control, find out if and how React is externalised. If it is not externalised, I think you cannot solve this problem in the context of Electron. If it is externalised as a global, put React into your .html file and make your main program depend on that as well.