# React how can i use @import

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i use @import to import my components in my scripts from other folders in my react project.

For example i have a folder structure like this

```
src
|
--- App.jsx
|
--- pages
|     |___ home.jsx
|
|
--- components
      |__ HomeComponent.jsx
```

How can i use in home.jsx

```
import HomeComponent from "@components/HomeComponent"
```

if i just try to use import HomeComponent from "@components/HomeComponent" like
this i get error module not found.

Comment: It is my understanding that in order to use `@components` and have it refer to the `components` folder under `src`, one needs to set-up an alias. Do you know if you use webpack - and if so, please [try this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) for more specifics.

Comment: you can use babel path aliases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799049/how-to-use-babel-on-files-that-imports-using-path-aliases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a relative import from `pages/home.jsx` like this

```
import HomeComponent from "../components/HomeComponent"
```

Here `../` means you are going up one directory level and then into `components` directory

You can also perform absolute imports by setting up additional tools like babel or webpack. An absolute import would look like this when you have set `src` as your root directory

```
import HomeComponent from "components/HomeComponent"
```

If you are using `create-react-app`, this setup is easy to do as all the tooling is already handled by `create-react-app`

You can read about it here under the absolute imports section - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/

Answer (score 1):

## babel-plugin-module-resolver

This plugin can simplify the require/import paths in your project. For example, instead of using complex relative paths like `../../../../utils/my-utils`, you can write `@utils/my-utils`. It will allow you to work faster since you won't need to calculate how many levels of directory you have to go up before accessing the file.

```
// Use this:
import MyUtilFn from 'utils/MyUtilFn';
// Instead of that:
import MyUtilFn from '../../../../utils/MyUtilFn';

// And it also work with require calls
// Use this:
const MyUtilFn = require('utils/MyUtilFn');
// Instead of that:
const MyUtilFn = require('../../../../utils/MyUtilFn');
```

Install the plugin

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

or

```
yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

Specify the plugin in your `.babelrc` with the custom root or alias. Here's an example:

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"],
      "alias": {
        "test": "./test",
        "underscore": "lodash"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

**.babelrc.js version**
Specify the plugin in your `.babelrc.js` file with the custom root or alias. Here's an example:

```
const plugins = [
  [
    require.resolve('babel-plugin-module-resolver'),
    {
      root: ["./src/"],
      alias: {
        "test": "./test"
      }
    }

  ]

];
```

Good example: https://gist.github.com/nodkz/41e189ff22325a27fe6a5ca81df2cb91